# Managing nested Redux containers without passing props?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

Given a component hierarchy like this:

```
<TodoList>
  <Todo>
    <TodoHeader/>
    <TodoBody>
      <TodoDetails>
        <TodoStatus />
      <TodoDetails>
      <TodoDescription />
    <TodoBody>
  <Todo>
</TodoList>
```

...and a store like this:

```
{
  todos: [
    { id: 1, status: "INCOMPLETE", header: "title one", description: "do a something" },
    { id: 2, status: "INCOMPLETE", header: "title two", description: "something else" },
    { id: 3, status: "COMPLETE", header: "title three", description: "one more thing" },
  ]
}
```

Is there a good way for the nested `TodoStatus` component to connect to the store without having to pass the `id` down
the component hierarchy as props? For example, `Todo` could set `currentTodoId = 1` as context, which would be available
for child reducers, but are there alternatives to that? Maybe a way for the parent component to reduce the store down to
a single todo that child components would then be able to see...?

At this point, you're probably wanting to ask "why"? Well, consider that there may be several levels of strictly presentational components in between the `TodoList` (which is operating on the array of todos) and the nested `TodoStatus` (which only wants to operate on a single todo). Having to pass the `todoId` down through a hierarchy like this is pretty painful:

```
<TodoList>
  <Todo todoId={1}>
    <SomeAnimation todoId={1}>
      <SomeLayout todoId={1}>
        <SomeOtherAnimation todoId={1}>
          <SomeDebugContainer todoId={1}>
            <TodoHeader todoId={1}>
            <TodoBody todoId={1}>
              <TodoDetails todoId={1}>
                <TodoStatus todoId={1}> // yay!
```

At this point, I'm imagining that this is specifically what React context is good for, so there's probably not a Redux-specific pattern, but I'd like to be wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do they all need to accept `id` as an argument?

Usually some component higher in the hierarchy (e.g. `Todo`) would accept either `id` or `todo`, but the components below would be more specific in what they accept, e.g.

```
function Todo({ todo }) {
  return (
     <SomeAnimation>
        <SomeLayout>
          <SomeOtherAnimation>
            <SomeDebugContainer>
              <TodoHeader title={todo.title} />
              <TodoBody {...todo} />
            </SomeDebugContainer>
          </SomeOtherAnimation>
        </SomeLayout>
     </SomeAnimation>
  )
}
```

In this example, `TodoHeader` just receives a `title` prop directly. If it needs more props, you can spread over `todo` properties with `{...todo}` like I do in `<TodoBody>`. It is not obvious from your example why components like `SomeAnimation` would need to know the todo ID either—presumably passing some visual properties of it would be enough.

Similarly, inner components like `TodoBody` might pass some of their props down, but again, this doesn’t have to be the ID:

```
function TodoBody({ title, text, status }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <TodoDetails text={text} />
      <TodoStatus status={status} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In general, deep trees returned from `render()` usually mean your component structure is suboptimal. You don’t have to use `this.props.children` in every component—feel free to keep components in control over their own rendering, and only pass what is necessary to them. Sometimes passing an `id` is convenient, other times passing data directly makes dependencies more explicit.

Comment: Thanks! In this example, I've shown the full DOM where all the intermediary components are available, but I meant to imply that the parent (that owns `todo`) doesn't actually directly access the deeply nested children. The `Todo` component might simply render the `SomeAnimation` component, for example, which then renders its own children, etc. etc.

In this scenario, you need to pass *something* down all the way through the hierarchy; the `id` was an example of that. I was wondering if there were other patterns to allow for this nicely.

Comment: Specifically, in cases like this (where the parent manages a list of `XYZ` objects), so you want to have some components that do the presentation logic for an individual `XYZ` logic. It would be useful, then, for the parent to be able to reduce the state tree accessible to the individual components so they can write reducers relative to just that individual `XYZ` state. It seems like this type of behaviour is accessible with some Redux addons like `redux-cursor`, but I was wondering if there are existing patterns that I'm missing.

Comment: It’s hard to answer this question then without a very specific example. That said prop passing is absolutely normal in React, and unless we’re talking about >10 props for every component, I don’t quite see the issue.

Comment: Fair enough - prop passing certainly works, it can just be a bit irritating to have to "plumb" through other components sometimes when they have no need for those props (just passing down to a nested child). There's definitely an alternative, which is using `context` to make things like `currentTodoId` available to a nested reducer, but it doesn't look like something like that is built into "core" Redux. That's fine by me :)

Comment: I’m confused why you say “reducer” here because we are talking about component nesting, are we not? As for the irritation of plumbing—perhaps it’s worth keeping `currentTodoId` itself in the store? Then you can `connect()` the leaf component without passing the props down. Alternatively, you can do something like `<Something><Todo id={id} /></Something>` so it becomes `this.props.children`, which can then be passed from `Something` through a tree of components without knowing it’s a `Todo`.

Comment: `currentTodoId` being available in the store doesn't really work, though, since there may be multiple active at one time.

Comment: Ideally, there'd be a relatively simple way for a nested component to connect directly to the store and only see the state it's supposed to see - e.g. a single `Todo`, not an array of `Todo`s. That way, you could write the reducer and actions to be scoped to just that component state, and it would avoid having to "plumb" things like the particular ID down through the component hierarchy. It doesn't seem like this is part of Redux core, but there are some addons that appear to take this approach...

Comment: Well, if this is *really* a problem, you can put `todoId` in context. I would not recommend it though. :-)

Comment: Haha, neither would I!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I'll stick to prop passing and keeping the component hierarchy under control. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Connect seems to be a bad idea, as you said each Todo is a presentation component and should ignore anything about redux store or application.

I have the same problem on a project, for the moment I think it seems painful but it make each element reusable and simplify the code (not the quantity of code but the logic). May be you can simplify your  dom/component structure, using react children encapsulation to limit the number of "levels"

Not sure I helped a lot. If you find a great solution I will glad to read it.

Good luck